# How can i use the getter/setter of a Call-Method from Example Code in MailComposer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, call, getter

i have a question regarding the call-methods handling in object-c.

I downloaded the apple sample code for the mail composer (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html).

When the user touches the "Compose Mail"-Button in the sample-code the Methode

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    NSLog(@"MCVC displayComposerSheet");
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];


    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"rainy"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

will be loaded and the mailcomposerview appears.

After the user sends the mail or cancels it the following methode will be called

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    NSLog(@"MCVC mailComposeController");
    message.hidden = NO;
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            message.text = @"Result: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            message.text = @"Result: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            message.text = @"Result: sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            message.text = @"Result: failed";
            break;
        default:
            message.text = @"Result: not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in which you can implement your code.

My Question now is how can i get for example the data of "toRecipients", "ccRecipients", "setMessageBody", "setSubject" etc.?

Is this even possible? I dont know how to use the getter in the `"- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error"-Methode`

If i forgot any informations you need i will post them :)

Thanks for everyone who can help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple API:

Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

Looking at this, and also trying out various names that would be appropriate for the ivars in the didFinishWithResult: method, it seems it is NOT possible to get this information from the prebuilt MFMailComposeViewController

you could subclass this class or roll your own to get the functionality..but that seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: But even extending functionality of `MFMailComposeViewController` could cause problems on the app review if the `Apple API` tells `...and must not be modified by your application...``